# How can I subtract large numbers without using a calculator?

Tags: integers

I am looking for the easiest way to subtract large numbers from one another.
Numbers such as:
$$
362354662,\;200519663,\;755393929,\;215879628,\;514121473,\;321038254,\;736846120
$$
Without the use of a calculator...

Thanks!

Na.

Comment: The digit-by-digit method which everyone learns in school is the easiest way (and the only way I can think of at the moment)

Comment: [Adding the nines complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements) gives you a way to do it without borrowing if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The digit-by-digit method that I learned in school works well.  Taking two of your example numbers $$\begin {align} 362354662&\\ \underline{-200519663}&\\
161834999 \end {align}$$
Where you start from the ones column.  You can't subtract $3$ from $2$, so borrow a $10$ from the tens and $12-3=9$  Then in the tens column we have $5-6$ so we have to borrow again.  Keep going.  With a little practice, this is very fast.